# Euclidean distance and connecting lines between polygons using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, polyline-creation

I have a large set of polygons. I want to

(1) calculate pairwise distances between polygons (so one polygon should be connected to several others). I can do this using the generate table in ArcMap.

and then

(2) I want a lines connecting these polygons (again one to many/many to one) that can link to the  distance file.

The only way I can think of doing this is through linkage mapper, but I dont want all the least-cost etc analysis, which is very time consuming.

Is there a simpler way to do this using ArcMap 10.5?

Comment: Let's focus on ArcMap in this question. You can always ask about doing the same thing using QGIS in a separate question. What is "linkage mapper"?  If provides a table containing X1,Y1 and X2,Y2 then creating single segment features between them may be straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is modification of polygon neighbors table so it will look like that:

[image]

where pairs of coordinates are centroids of polygons. Convert table into 2 sets of points, merge them and use pair ID as line ID in points to line tool:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, that worked. I have a couple of questions next to the steps. Steps (Arc10.5)
1. I used the generate near-table, selected the location Box. This produced a table similar to the one you have. 
2. I did not get a column or anything analogous to your PairColumn. I created a new field & populated it with the FiD. (Is there a way to get the PairColumn)?
3. I created 2 event layers: one using the From X and Y and another one using Near X and Y. (is there another way to create points from a table?)
4. Merged the event layers 
5. Used the points to line tool and used the PairID.

Comment: I used polygon neighbor tool first and transfer of coordinates later. Near table is subjective, how many neighbors? Anyway, mark as solved, please, if worked.